# How to stop logging in MongoDB Ruby client?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm connecting to MongoDB using the Ruby Driver and I don't see how to turn off the logging. Here's the current output from an IRB session:

```
D, [2015-06-06T11:01:05.622513 #30526] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=admin.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 0.7546ms
D, [2015-06-06T11:01:15.623716 #30526] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=admin.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 0.7083ms
....
```

It repeats the lines above over and over, which makes it very difficult to type in the IRB session.  Here's the code used to create the client connection:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb')
```

Anyone know how to turn that off?  FWIW, I tried setting `verbose=false` in `/etc/mongod.conf` and that did not help.

Comment: For future visitors, if you want beautiful colored logging similar to active record, you might want to look at the [mongo beautiful logger gem](https://github.com/ibraheemdev/mongo_beautiful_logger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Mongo's logger instance and/or verbosity.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/#logger):

> You can either use the default driver logger or set your own. To set your own:
>
> ```
> Mongo::Logger.logger = other_logger
> ```
>
> Please see the [Ruby Logger documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) for more information on the default logger API and available levels.
>
> To change the logger level:
>
> ```
> Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::WARN
> ```